# How do I fill in the gap between these two td's?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I want the space between these two td's to be the same light grey as the background on the left.

I tried adding a td in between them, then making it the right color. It was too big and I couldn't change its size or get it to be flush with the left td.

It seems like it should be easy to fix but I've been stuck on it for two days.

Here is the HTML for the whole table. The cells in question are near the bottom of the table.

```css
#donation{
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;

}

.underline{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;

}

#darkgrey{
    width: 41px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
}

#receipt{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#393939;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;

}

#links{
    background-color: white;
    font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}

#fillblank{

}
```

```html
<table id='donation'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <p class='lightgrey center'>
        You have donated
      </p>
      <p class='blackbold center'>
        $00.00
      </p>
      <p class='lightgrey center'>
        to
      </p>
      <p class='blackbold center'>
        Innocence Project
      </p>
    </tr>
    <tr class='underline'>
      <td class='lightgrey left'>
        Charged Amount
      </td>
      <td class='lightgrey right'>
        $00.00
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='underline'>
      <td class='lightgrey left'>
        Donation Date
      </td>
      <td class='lightgrey right'>
        MM/DD/YYYY 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='underline'>
      <td class ='lightgrey left'>
        Donation Number
      </td>
      <td class ='lightgrey right'>
        XXXXXXXX 
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id='blank'>
      <td>
        &nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
      <div id ='darkgrey'><img src='receipt.png'></div>
      </td>
      <!-- <td id='fillblank'>
      </td> -->
      <td id ='receipt'>
        Your official receipt is attached to this email
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r8b5nsuo/

Answer (score 1):

There is no space between `td`s. The white "space" you see is white background of left `td`.

**Explanation**

`<div id="dargkgrey">` has fixed width set to 41px and margin set to auto (so it is centered in `td`) however `td` id wider than 41px because of some of corresponding above `td`s has text which is wider (entire column has to have the same width).

**Solution**

Add the desired `background-color` to `td` instead of `<div id="dargkgrey">`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin on "darkgey" and set the same background colour on its parent "td". Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/r8b5nsuo/

```
  <tr>
     <td class="imagediv">
         <div id ='darkgrey'><img src='receipt.png'></div>
     </td>

     <td id ='receipt'>
          Your official receipt is attached to this email
      </td>
  </tr>


 #darkgrey{
   width: 41px;
   height: 50px;
   background-color: darkgrey;    
   padding: 0;
 }   

 .imagediv {  
    background-color: #f8f8f8;   
 }
```